# How to create a CSS semi circle with logo inside?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a footer where in the upper part there is a semi circle on the center with a logo inside of it. I have my sample code here, but the problem with it is that the logo is bound on the height of the footer div.

[image: Sample Footer Image]

```css
html,
body,
.container,
.content {
  height: 100%;
}
.container,
.content {
  position: relative;
}
.proper-content {
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 40px;
  /* >= navbar height */
}
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -100px;
  /* same as the footer */
}
.push {
  height: 100px;
  /* same as the footer */
}
.footer-logo {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("gaslogo.png");
  background-position: 10% 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
.footer-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.halfCircleBottom {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 100px 100px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-logo">dsad</div>
  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <footer>
      <center>
        <div class="halfCircleBottom"></div>
      </center>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a `:before` pseudo element with background image for the circle.

```css
.footer {
  background: crimson;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: crimson url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fogjj.jpg") center / cover;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this is what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished what you need this way:

Changed your HTML a bit:

```
<div class="footer-wrap">

    <div class="halfCircleBottom">

            <img src="insert your image with the same width as the parent div"/>

    </div>

            <footer>
                        <center>

                        </center>
            </footer>

</div><!--end footer wreap-->
```

Then added and changed one of your css declarations:

```
footer {
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
}

.halfCircleBottom{
    position: absolute;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -72%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML:

```
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}

.footer{
  height: 100px;
  background: #cf9f3f;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer:before{
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #cf9f3f;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: -52px auto 0;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/vc4mvwd2/